# Reading a space indented List<string>

Tags: c#, text, recursion, indentation

I have a List where the contents of the list are indented by spaces.

There are two columns (a control type as well as an ID) and the columns are of fixed length.

The indention denotes the parent – child relationship between the elements.

As an example:

```
    Modal                    000
     Child1                  100    
      Child1                 110
     Child2                  200
      Child1                 210
      Child2                 220
       Child1                221
     Child3                  300
```

To hold the Information I have the following simple classes:

```
class CustomDefinition
{
    public List<CustomControl> Children { get; set; }
}

class CustomControl
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CustomControl> Children { get; set; }
}
```

The plan is to have an instance of the `CustomDefinition` class which will contain the root element whilst the other elements, being children of the root element, will be in the children collection of the root itself. The root element will have a `ParentId` of `000` whereas the children should receive the id of its parent element.

As the children themselves have children, they are to be placed in their own children collection.

I have an Extension method found here which provides me with the index of the first non-space character, but I have no idea how I should continue:

```
    private static void _TestParse(List<string> items)
    {
        CustomDefinition definition = new CustomDefinition() {
            Children = new List<CustomControl>()
        };

        int currentControlId = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            // the current element
            var control = items[i];

            // the aforementioned extension method
            var controlIndex = control.IndexOf<char>(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c));

            // fixed length for the first column
            var controlName = control.Substring(0, 20).Trim();      

            // fixed length for the second column
            var controlId = control.Substring(20, 3);

            int.TryParse(controlId, out currentControlId);

            definitions.Children.Add(new CustomControl() {
                Id = currentControlId,
                Name = controlName
            });

            // i need to find if the current element has children
            // (in the example above the root element has 3 children)
            // then add these children to the current element

            var currentElement = definitions.Children
                .Find(x => x.Id == currentControlId);

            // then do this for all children and their children?!
        }
    }
```

I do hope this all makes sense and I appreciate any help whatsoever.

Comment: What is the question? How to build the tree of controls?

Comment: I do apologize. Yes, the question would be how would I be able to build the tree of controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I start with this data:

```
var data = new []
{
    "Modal                    000",
    " Child1                  100",
    "  Child1                 110",
    " Child2                  200",
    "  Child1                 210",
    "  Child2                 220",
    "   Child1                221",
    " Child3                  300",
};
```

Then I can create a list of raw items like this:

```
var items =
    from x in data
    let idText = x.Substring(20)
    let indentedText = x
        .Substring(0, x.Length - idText.Length)
        .TrimEnd()
    let name = indentedText.Trim()
    let indent = indentedText.Length - name.Length
    select new
    {
        id = int.Parse(idText),
        name,
        indent,
    };
```

And that gives me:

[image: items]

Now I can use this code to turn it into the desired object model:

```
var itemDictionary = new Dictionary<int, CustomControl>();

foreach (var item in items)
{
    itemDictionary[item.indent] = new CustomControl()
    {
        Id = item.id,
        Name = item.name,
        Children = new List<CustomControl>(),
    };
    if (item.indent != 0)
    {
        itemDictionary[item.indent].ParentId =
            itemDictionary[item.indent - 1].Id;
        itemDictionary[item.indent - 1]
            .Children.Add(itemDictionary[item.indent]);
    }
}
```

I then get this output:

[image: result]

Comment: what tool are you visualizing this in?

Comment: @Default I believe this is LinqPad

Answer (score 0):

In the `Main` method I created sample data, initialized your classes, and performed parsing of the data. There is a recursive method that is responsible for searching for parent of the current node. I had to modify your `CustomControl` class. Looking at the structure of your IDs in the sample it makes more sens to keep them as strings (revert it to int if you prefer them that way - will only require slight modifications of my code). I also added a property to your `CustomControl`. It's responsible for remembering the indentation level of the item.

More explanations in the code as comments. Below the code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create sample data
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        items.Add("Modal                    000");
        items.Add(" Child1                  100");
        items.Add("  Child1                 110");
        items.Add(" Child2                  200");
        items.Add("  Child1                 210");
        items.Add("  Child2                 220");
        items.Add("   Child1                221");
        items.Add(" Child3                  300");

        // Initialize the collection object
        CustomDefinition customDefinition = new CustomDefinition();
        customDefinition.Children = new List<CustomControl>();

        // Keep reference to the previous item in the list
        CustomControl prevItem = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; ++i)
        {
            // Find indentation level
            int currentIndent = items[i].TakeWhile(c => char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).Count();
            string[] itemIdPair = items[i].Trim().Split(' ').ToArray();

            // Create CustomControl from data
            CustomControl currentItem = new CustomControl();
            // Before split the string is trimmed so name is always first item and ID - last one
            currentItem.Id = (itemIdPair[itemIdPair.Length -1]);
            currentItem.Name = itemIdPair[0];
            currentItem.IndentLevel = currentIndent;

            // Add CustomControl reference to the collection
            customDefinition.Children.Add(currentItem);

            // First item - main node
            if (prevItem == null)
            {
                prevItem = currentItem;
            }
            // Siblings - get the same parent
            else if (currentItem.IndentLevel == prevItem.IndentLevel)
            {
                CustomControl parent = customDefinition.Children.Where(item => item.Id == prevItem.ParentId).FirstOrDefault();
                currentItem.ParentId = parent.Id;
                if (parent.Children == null)
                    parent.Children = new List<CustomControl>();
                parent.Children.Add(currentItem);
            }
            // Child
            else if (currentItem.IndentLevel > prevItem.IndentLevel)
            {
                currentItem.ParentId = prevItem.Id;
                if (prevItem.Children == null)
                    prevItem.Children = new List<CustomControl>();
                prevItem.Children.Add(currentItem);
            }
            // Item's level is higher than the previous item - find how far does it go and
            // get the parent for the item
            else
            {
                // parent's indentation will be one level higher than the current one (currentIndent - 1)
                // try to find it recursively
                // Use the previous node in the list of nodes as the starting point
                CustomControl parent = GoBackToLevel(customDefinition.Children, prevItem, currentIndent - 1);
                currentItem.ParentId = parent.Id;
                if (parent.Children == null)
                    parent.Children = new List<CustomControl>();
                parent.Children.Add(currentItem);
            }

            // Replace the reference to the previous item.
            prevItem = currentItem;
        }
    }

    private static CustomControl GoBackToLevel(List<CustomControl> items, CustomControl start, int parentLevel)
    {
        // Find a parent of the starting CustomControl using the control's ID.
        CustomControl parent = items.Where(item => item.Id == start.ParentId).FirstOrDefault();

        // Does the parent has the expected indentation level? Yes - get the parent
        // else use the parent as the starting point for search instead.
        if (parent.IndentLevel == parentLevel)
            return parent;
        else
            return GoBackToLevel(items, parent, parentLevel);
    }
```

And the modified `CustomControl`:

```
class CustomControl
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CustomControl> Children { get; set; }
    public int IndentLevel { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hello Piotr and thank you for your idea.

Without looking at this in an editor I believe that I'm also adding every element to the root but I can change that of course.

It also looks like the second child (with the id 200) receives only the one child (210) instead of two children (210; 220).

It does look very promising, thank you very much!

I will confirm the solution once I have confirmed it in code.

Comment: I fixed the problem with the child node. On the level of sibling now I'm using parent's Id to get the parent.